# problems to verify ecdsa certificate

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

I'm working on an application which uses ECDSA certificates. After the cert generation, they should be verified but currently the following error is received:

```
C = CA, ST = BC, L = City, O = Corp, OU = Software, emailAddress = administrators@corp.com, CN = va.corp.com
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
```

That is when the following command is invoked: `openssl verify -CAfile ca-chain en-cert.pem`

The certs are generated using the CSR like `openssl ca -in CSR`

How can the certificate be verified properly against the ca-cert/ca-chain?
`openssl verify -CAfile en-cert.pem en-cert.pem` returns `OK`

Comment: I think it's a self-signed certificate. There is no CA. What is the issuer of a certificate? Check with this command: openssl.exe x509 -in en-cert.pem -noout -issuer. If the issuer is the same as subject CN, then it is a self-signed certificate and that's why the last verify command is working.

Answer (score 1):

> The certs are generated using...

If you generate certificates, you get self signed certificates.
The message *self signed certificate* says exactly that.

Not you should generate certificate, but a CA. To get a valid certificate, you should send CSR to a CA. After you obtain a certificate from CA, load CA chain for this CA. Then you can verify your certificate.